# Irreducible $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ with roots $r, s$ such that $rs = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots, irreducible-polynomials

> If $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is irreducible and has two roots $r,s$ such that $rs = 1$, then $p(x)$ is of even degree.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. My initial idea was to consider the field tower $\mathbb{Q}(r, r+s) \supseteq \mathbb{Q}(r+s) \supseteq \mathbb{Q}$. We know that $\mathbb{Q}(r, r+s) = \mathbb{Q}(r)$, since $r+s \in \mathbb{Q}(r)$. Then,
$$\operatorname{deg}p(x) = [\mathbb{Q}(r): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(r+s)(r): \mathbb{Q}(r+s)][\mathbb{Q}(r+s): \mathbb{Q}].$$
Note that $x^2 - (r+s)x + 1 \in \mathbb{Q}(r+s)[X]$ and has roots $r$ and $s$. If we could show that this polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(r+s)[X]$ or, equivalently, that $r \notin \mathbb{Q}(r+s)$, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(r, r+s)/\mathbb{Q}(r+s)$ would have degree $2$ and, therefore, $\operatorname{deg}p(x) = 2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$. However, I wasn't able to come up with a proof of this. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Hint:  $\,f(r)= 0\Rightarrow s = r^{-1}\,$ is a root of the reversed (reciprocal) polynomial $\,x^d f(x^{-1}),\ d = \deg f\ \ $

Comment: I thought about the reciprocal polynomial earlier but couldn't make progress with that idea either.

Comment: Following @BillDubuque 's hint, you may want to compare the polynomial $p(x)$ and its reciprocal. Can't you say something interesting about them? (Btw I'm also thinking about a way to solve the problem using what you've done so far ; for the moment I don't see it)

Comment: @Suzet What I was thinking is to calculate explicitly a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(r+s)$, which I believe would have to be something like $\{1, r+s, r^2+s^2, \ldots, r^n+s^n\}$, since their products are going to be rationals (I could be very wrong about this though). We then show that it is impossible to write $r$ as a linear combination of them.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159574

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Bill Dubuque's comment: let deg$(p(x)) = d$. Then the reciprocal polynomial of $p(x)$ is given by $x^{d}p(x^{-1})$ and has root $s = r^{-1}$.

Note that $p(x)$ and its reciprocal share a root and are both irreducible, hence $x^{d}p(x^{-1})$ is a non-zero constant multiple of $p(x)$:

$$p(x) = cx^{d}p(x^{-1})$$

for some $c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Furthermore, $p(x)$ is irreducible, hence $1$ and $-1$ are not roots of $p(x)$.

If we insert $1$ into $p(x)$ we get $p(1) = c(1)^{d}p(1) \neq 0$, so $c = 1$. Now inserting $-1$ into $p(x)$ gives $p(-1) = (-1)^{d}p(-1)$ which implies $(-1)^{d} = 1$. Thus, $d$ must be even.